# Doxygen, How to document function pointers in a typedef struct

Tags: c, documentation, doxygen

Doxygen v1.9.6
I have a typedef struct with function pointers in my header file a.h

```
/**
 * @defgroup _xModule X Module
 * Generic documentation for this module goes here.
 * @{
 * @ingroup _mainModule
 */

/**
 * Public x interface.
 * All x has to expose this interface by attaching the appropriate
 * function to each pointer.
 */
typedef struct {
    ExResult (*Init     ) (uint8_t indx);                 ///< Initialize x.
    bool     (*IsUpdated) (uint8_t indx,   uint8_t ch);   ///< Returns true if x been updated.
    double   (*SetOption) (uint8_t option, double value); ///< x specific options/commands.
} xINTERFACE;

///@}
```

This only generates a brief description under "Data Fields" and under "Field Documentation" it generates an empty description (because I have no `@details` somewhere).

What is the best way to document this as a "function", since it is a function pointer. I don't want to add it at the typedef struct because it would clutter the code to much.

I would like to put this description in my a.dox instead.

How can I document each "function" (with parameters and return type) in this separate a.dox file?

```
/**
 @defgroup _mainModule x Main module
 @{
 INTRODUCTION
 ============
 Yada yada yoda...
 @}
*/
```

This is the config diff (doxygen -x)

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.9.6
PROJECT_NAME           = X
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 02
PROJECT_BRIEF          = "X"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = .
REPEAT_BRIEF           = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
PYTHON_DOCSTRING       = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 2
ALIASES                = todo=\todo
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = YES
NUM_PROC_THREADS       = 0
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = YES
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = NO
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = NO
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = NO
QUIET                  = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = NO
INPUT                  = ../../Firmware/src \
                         ./ \
                         .
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.h \
                         *.md \
                         *.dox
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = */spi.h \
                         */spi.c
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = __attribute__
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 1
USE_MATHJAX            = YES
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@2
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = NO
HAVE_DOT               = YES
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 8
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = YES
DOT_PATH               = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin"
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 1000
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = YES
```

Comment: What did you try? What are you missing? Please show also the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile` (in the question!) which are the settings specific for your project.

Comment: @albert Added some details for you.

Comment: Maybe best to have a look at a command like `\snippet`